# Prove that if $\|A\|<1$, then $(I+A)^{-1}=I-A+A^2-A^3+\cdots$.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, inverse

Prove that if $\|A\|<1$, then $(I+A)^{-1}=I-A+A^2-A^3+\cdots$.

I'm not sure how to do this. I know the result for $(I-A)^{-1}$, but that won't help me.

Comment: Is your norm submultiplicative?

Comment: The point being that $||A|| = ||-A||$, so if you know the result for $(I-A)^{-1}$, apply it with $-A$ replacing $A$.  Or have we misunderstood you?

Comment: @MichaelHardy The [first edit after a question was put no hold](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1766179/revisions) moves it into [reopen review queue](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/620328), see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821). Which is a reason why minor edits are not useful in such situations. An edit which adresses the reasons why the question was closed would be more helpful. (And such edit is more likely to come from the OP.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak : I didn't know that, but now I've explicitly voted to reopen. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the result for $(I-A)^{-1}$ you can employ it: if $\|A\|<1$, then $\|-A\|=\|A\|<1$; hence $I+A = I -(-A)$ is invertible and $$(I+A)^{-1} = (I-(-A))^{-1} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-A)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nA^n.$$

Answer (score -2):

Suppose $X=I-A+A^2-\cdots$. Then
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(I+A)X &=& (I+A)I - (I+A)A + (I+A)A^2 -\cdots \\
&=& (I + A) - (A+A^2) + (A^2+A^3) - \cdots \\
&=& I + (A - A) - (A^2 - A^2) + (A^3 - A^3) - \cdots \\
&=& I
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Since $(I+A)X=I$, we must have $X=(I+A)^{-1}I=(I+A)^{-1}$